# Grails Async OnError(){}

Tags: grails

I've tried to use the Async method in grails, but the task hides all the exceptions. This makes the debug hard, so I tried to use the onError method, but it doesn't work.

The code is like this:

```
job1=task{println "something"}
job1.onError(){Throwable t ->
  println "An error occured ${t.message}"
}
```

Comment: You should add a more complete example: a println statement doesn't trigger any error.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
job1=task{
    println "something";
    def ex = new Exception("Exception when doing something");
    throw ex;
}

job1.onError(){Throwable t ->
    println "An error occured ${t.message}"
}
```

Comment: The onError Still doesn't work. It seems the code didn't go to onError closure